# Install dotnet (.NET) software on windows using inno setup

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, installation, inno-setup

I have made a software using .NET 2.0 framework and I want that it should install properly on all versions of Windows: Vista/7/8/8.1

The problem is that Vista has 2.0 by default but .NET 2.0 is an optional OS component in Win 7/8/8.1 and is not pre-installed by default. So, if I try to install .NET 2.0 based software on Win 7/8/8.1 then will the OS always install and execute it without any error or do I have to add any file in the setup to support .NET 2.0 exe in Win 7/8/8.1

I do not want to include .NET framework in my setup.

Comment: This is a pure .NET app. deployment question with no relation to Inno Setup. Once you'll find a way what to do, it may become related to Inno Setup, but not yet...

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you don't try to execute any .NET code during the install itself, then the installation will complete successfully regardless of whether .NET is installed or not.  The application will not actually run without .NET installed, however.

.NET 2.0 is a subset of .NET 3.0 and 3.5 (but not 4.0), so installing any of the first three is sufficient to allow .NET 2.0 apps to run.  Installing .NET 4.0 *can* also work, but your app must contain a config setting explicitly indicating that it's safe to run using the 4.0 runtime in that case.

From Vista onwards, I believe that the OS is smart enough to offer to install the framework itself if the user tries to run an application that requires it, and it is not yet installed.  But you shouldn't take my word for it; you should test this yourself, using a VM.

Alternatively (particularly if you do need to run .NET code during the install) you may need to download and/or run the framework installer yourself using custom code, or invoke the Windows component installer directly.